# Finding the largest root of $2x^2+3x+6=7x\sqrt{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Find the largest root of
> $$2x^2+3x+6=7x\sqrt{x+2}$$

Squaring both sides gives us a 4th-degree polynomial, not ideal.

If we can factor the left hand side into something similar to the square root, we might be able to reduce complexity by substitution.

However, LHS doesn't seem to be factorizeable, either.

Comment: The $4$th degree polynomial factors into two quadratics.

Comment: @Blue is finding that easily doable by hand? I find it hard to do so.

Comment: I don't have any hard-and-fast rules, but it's possible to get lucky w/ educated guessing. We start w/ $4x^4-37x^3-65x^2+36x+36$. The $37$ seems *suspiciously-close* to $36$, which suggests grouping $4x^4-36x^3$; the remaining $-1x^3$ then gets the compatible grouping $-1x^3+9x^2$. That leaves $-74x^2+36x+36$. The $74$ "wants" to be separated into $72$ and $2$; we can fill out $-2x^2$ as the group $-2x^2+18x$, which leaves $-72x^2+18x+36$. Each term finds a home with a previous group: $4x^4-36x^3-72x^2=4x^2(x^2-9x-18)$, $-1x^3+9x^2+18x=-1x(x^2-9x-18)$, $-2x^2+18x+36=-2(x^2-9x-18)$. (continued)

Comment: (continuing) Of course, if you guess wrong, then you can waste a lot of time. There are probably algorithms for determining the factors without guessing, but I don't know any of the top of my head. ... What's the context of this problem? How "clever" a solution might be expected? (Your idea of factoring in a way that's somehow compatible with the square root seems like a good one, but I also don't see any obvious way to make it work.)

Comment: Most of the factorization methods, take linear factor test for example, focuses on finding factors of degree 1, so that's what came to my mind first, but this question factorizes into quadratics, so your factorization method should be the most suitable for this question (besides using a calculator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rush to square equations.  Instead, first try to eliminate surds via substitution.

Let $y=\sqrt{x+2}$.  Then the equation becomes

$$2x^2 - 7xy + 3y^2=0$$
Which you can factor as a quadratic
$$(2x-y)(x-3y)=0$$
Or (using $x=y^2-2$) $$(2y^2-y-4)(y^2-3y-2)=0$$
Find the largest root of each quadratic, then the overall largest root, then get back to $x$.

Comment: Maybe the constant $+6$ in the original problem is meant to be solved by this method.